# Powershell Connect-AzureAD error "accessing_ws_metadata_exchange_failed"

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I m writing a Powershell script where I need to connect to Azure Active Directory using code.

If I connect through prompt it works fine but using code (providing user id and password in code) it throws the following error:

> Connect-AzureAD : One or more errors occurred.:
>   accessing_ws_metadata_exchange_failed: Accessing WS metadata exchange
>   failed At C:\Users\yawer.iqbal\Desktop\Untitled3.ps1:8 char:3
>   +   Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential -TenantID $tenant

Here is my code:

```
$User = "myid@outlook.com"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "*******" -AsPlainText -Force
$tenant = "bingu12outlook.onmicrosoft.com"
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $User, $PWord
  Import-Module AzureAD
  Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential -TenantID $tenant
```

I have tried:
Adding this line but it do not work either:

```
[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
```

Please help

Comment: Is that a personal Microsoft account? I don't think you can do password auth in a script with federated accounts like that.

Comment: @juunas thanks it is a personal account with hotmail and I just have a Azure trial. sorry I didn't get what is fedrated account.

Comment: Could my reply solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what caused the issue, if it is acceptable, you can use a work account to do that, it works fine on my side.

First, navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the azure portal -> `Users` -> `New user`, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-users-azure-active-directory). Then you will get a work account like `xxx@bingu12outlook.onmicrosoft.com`, remember to reset the password when the first login.

My specific test command:

```
$User = "joyxx@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "xxxxxxx" -AsPlainText -Force
$tenant = "xxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $User,$PWord
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential -TenantID $tenant
```

[image]

Comment: It took 1 hour to find out that 'work' account (in B2C) is basically a user in AD with the username mandatory like xxx@yourdomain.onmicrosoft.com. No other domain names in username or not emal like usernames will work for the purpose. (a **verified and non-federated** custom domain name such as contoso.com will also work)